# Double.parseDouble(), Integer.parseInteger() --> cannot find symbol

Tags: java

Beginner Java learner here. Yesterday, the compiler was telling me that it "cannot find symbol" for `Double.parseDouble()`. The only "solution" I have right now to circumvent this "error" is to use `import java.lang.Double`. I never created any classes named `Double` or `Integer`, either. Can someone help me understand why the compiler is throwing this error and how to rectify it?

Sample code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class doubleparse
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        double number;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        String input = in.nextLine();
        number = Double.parseDouble(input);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
doubleparse.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
number = Double.parseDouble(input);
               ^
symbol:   method parseDouble(String)
location: class Double
1 error
```

Why does the compiler throw this message every time I use a parsing method? I've seen it throw this when I use the `Integer.parseInteger()` method too.

Comment: What is `class.parseClass()`? I don't see that in your code. What is the actual full error message you get?

Comment: `The only "solution" I have right now to circumvent this "error" is to use "import java.lang.Double"` In Java, you have to import these classes. That's normal behavior

Comment: Do you have your own `Double` and `Integer` classes in the project?

Comment: If you haven't already, you can read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706216/what-does-a-cannot-find-symbol-compilation-error-mean) on "Cannot find symbol" errors in Java.

Comment: @ByteHamster That is incorrect. `java.lang.*` is implicitly imported.

Comment: @ByteHamster I understand but I never have to to such import when I started learning Java.

Comment: @MaxVollmer I never created any classes named Double or Integer. Is that usually the reason why this error happens?

Comment: The error you get sounds like Java takes the wrong `Double` and `Integer` classes from somewhere. It would be good to know more about your project and Java version.

Comment: Especially because it says `class Double` and not `class java.lang.Double`, which sounds like it finds a class with that name in the default package.

Comment: @MaxVollmer Okay. Shall I look for any project that  shares the same Integer or Double in its class name then?

Comment: @mchlvncntry No problem.